# Building OpenGL applications not working in OSX 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

Building any C++/OpenGL application on my Macbook Pro with OSX 10.9/XCode6 is producing a blank window with nothing getting rendered. glClear works and I can see the clear color but drawing commands seem to just be ignored (no GL errors and I did not notice anything suspicious when stepping through the debugger). OpenGL profiler is just blank when I attach it.
GPU and display drivers are fine (steam games/prebuilt binaries work perfectly) and my build environment is sane as far as I know (I'm using MacPorts for thirdparty libs).

What could possibly be causing this issue?

### More Details:

I'm working on a multi-platform indie game and now trying to port the game to OSX. Our game uses SDL2 for OpenGL context management.
I wasted 2 days of debugging and couldn't find anything wrong with our code or any indication why no rendering is taking place at all. The same build files and libraries are used in Linux and the game works perfectly there. 
The issue is not related to my display hardware or driver since prebuilt binaries that use OpenGL work perfectly.

I wrote a couple of simple OpenGL Hello World applications ([this sample code for example](https://open.gl/content/code/c2_triangle.txt)) with different windowing/context libraries (SDL2, SFML and GLFW) on both XCode and NetBeans (to make sure XCode isn't the problem) and I'm getting the exact same result. Just a blank screen. 
This is really puzzling me and I've been trying to figure out how to fix it for several days so far.

Given the information I have the only likely suspects are the OpenGL libraries I'm getting linked to with the "-framework OpenGL" argument. But as far as I know those come prebuilt and ready with XCode so the chance of me doing something stupid and breaking them is minimal.

**Edit:**

Adding some more aggressive error checking gave me new leads. glewInit() call throws an invalid enum error but seems like that is intended behaviour and should be ignored [[source](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)].

Comment: Please include sample code in the question itself. Make sure you have a context made current; I don't know if the `sf::Window` constructor will make the created context current for you.

Comment: Have you tried building one of Apple's sample applications? You can find them through XCode's builtin help.

Comment: I haven't tried sample applications yet but that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a simple triangle to show!

Not sure how I missed it the first time but `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` is failing and causing an invalid operation GL error, it seems that on OSX OpenGL 3.2+ Core `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` fails if there is no vertex array object bound at the time of the call (which was the case in that particular sample code). I'm not certain why is that I think vertex attrib arrays are not functionally related to vertex array objects.

Anyway, since I managed to get some rendering out of OpenGL it means there is nothing wrong with my system/environment and therefore I'll consider my main issue resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: OpenGL 3.x on Mac OS only supports the core profile. In the core profile, calling `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` without a VAO bound is an error. Vertex array state is tracked in VAOs, that's exactly what they are for.

Comment: Apparently so. But that doesn't make much sense to me. I was under the impression that VAOs are nothing more than a utility to keep track of vertex array states as a group rather than individually and therefore it should be optional. `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` on the other hand is required for rendering which in effect makes VAOs mandatory on OSX 3.x core profile.

Comment: Yes, VAOs are mandatory in the OpenGL core profile. From the list of removed features in the spec: "The default vertex array object (the name zero) is also deprecated."

Comment: Vertex array modifications can happen on a "default" VAO 0 in compatibility mode. In core mode, that VAO does not exist. If you're used to VAOs and the core profile, what doesn't make much sense is modifying the state of an unbound object.

Comment: Aha I misunderstood the purpose of VAOs then. I'm not only porting to OSX I'm also upgrading renderer from OpenGL 2.0 to 3.X core and still running into incompatibilities between the two. Thanks for clarifying